# How to initiate a phone call from a hyperlink?

Tags: windows-10, dial-up

In the past, I've been annoyed by the `<a href="tel:###">` hyperlinks often used on webpages, but I wonder if they could be set up to do something useful or if a similar hyperlinked protocol could do something useful.

Is there a way to change the "application used" for `tel:` hyperlinks so that it actually uses a computer's modem to call the number? I tried clicking on such a link now and it just opens Skype for Business. I would have thought it would ask for the application to use, but it did not.

This way, for instance, if I was on a page of dial-up access numbers, I could simply click a number and it would seize control of the modem and - if free - place the call.

Note that I am specifically interested in placing a **real** phone call using a **real** modem. Useless apps like Skype for Business that merely place virtual calls are not useful to me, making the current implementation of the `tel:` hyperlink also useless unless I can change the application it launches to the dial up host.

When I go to *Default Programs* in Windows 10, the selection screen offered is not helpful. Basically it says, "use Skype for Business" or screw you - there doesn't seem to be a way to use a Win32 application here, and if there were, I'm not sure what the executable to the dialup interface is:

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate post. You'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone

Comment: @ErinThomas I don't see anything relevant on that page. That has to do with mobile devices.

Comment: @ErinThomas Not a duplicate. They are both about tel: links but in a completely different way. None of the answers in the other question has any baring on this.